# Getting user's input in NodeJS "readline" module

Tags: node.js, readline

In a NodeJS program, I want to accept input from console. I chose `readline` to do this. The code can be simplified as follow:

```js
const readline = require("readline"),
    rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

function getInput() {
    rl.question("", (ans) => {
        console.log(ans);
    })
}

getInput();
rl.close();
```

But every time I run this program, it exits before I could make any input.

I think the problem is caused by the statement `rl.close()`, it may close the interface before accepting any input. How can I avoid this?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `getInput` in a promise like this:

```
function getInput() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        rl.question("what's your option? ", (ans) => {
            console.log(ans);
            resolve(ans);
        });
    });
}

// and await here

await getInput();
rl.close();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It sais `await` can only be used in async functions: `await getInput();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: that's a different question but you can wrap it in an async method like this. `(async()=>{
await getInput();
rl.close();
})();
`

Comment: Or the old call back way `getInput().then(()=>{rl.close();})` if you are not comfortable with the `await` sytax.